# How can I resize a rendered ray traced image?

Tags: raytracing, sampling

Say I have rendered an HDR ray traced image with dimensions 1920x1080 (width x height) pixels and I want to instead represent it with dimensions 960x540. Assume as well that the image has not yet been gamma corrected (i.e. it is still in linear space). How should I go about downsampling the image such that I don't need to re-render the image in the new dimensions?

Comment: You can use any standard image downsampling method. There's nothing special about raytraced images that requires a different method.

Comment: Is part of the question whether or not downsampling should be done in linear or gamma corrected space? Linear space is always appropriate - GPUs can apply a degamma-regamma when resolving gamma-corrected multisample buffers.

Comment: I'm not asking about whether it should be done in linear or gamma space (I know that it should be done in linear space). @NathanReed could you suggest an easy to implement one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to downsample the image by a factor of 2 along each axis, a simple and easy thing to do is just average a 2×2 box of source pixels to generate each destination pixel. In pseudocode this would look like:

```
for dest_y = 0 to 540
    src_y = dest_y*2
    for dest_x = 0 to 960
        src_x = dest_x*2
        average = 0.25 * (src[src_y][src_x] + src[src_y][src_x+1] +
                          src[src_y+1][src_x] + src[src_y+1][src_x+1])
        dest[dest_y][dest_x] = average
```

This will do an okay job, but for higher-quality downsampling or resizing images to any size (not just neat integer factors), I suggest looking at the [stb_image_resize](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_resize.h) library. It's quite easy to use, supports either 8-bit or floating-point images with any number of channels, and gives good results.

Comment: I wonder if there are any high performance libraries out there instead of stb? Would halide support doing something like this?

Comment: @Decave I don't know off the top of my head, but I did find [this image-resizing sample](https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/apps/resize/resize.cpp) in the Halide repository.